# GKE cluster v1.2.4 - route recreation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created a 3 nodes GKE cluster which is running fine but I noticed a few times that my components are not able to reach the API Server during 3 or 4 minutes.

I recently had the same problem again on a fresh new cluster so I decided to look a bit closer. In the Compute Engine Operations section I noticed at the same time that the 3 routes had been removed and recreated 4 minutes later... This task had been scheduled by a @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com address so from the cluster directly I suppose.

What is causing this behavior, forcing the routes to be deleted and recreated randomly ?

Answer (score 1):

The apiserver may become unreachable if it gets temporarily overloaded or if it is upgraded or repaired. This should be unrelated to routes being removed and recreated, although it's possible that the node manager does not behave correctly when it is restarted.

Comment: So you are suggesting that the apiserver is being restarted due to temporary high ressources usage and it recreates the routes between my nodes on boot ? 

Is there a way I can confirm your hypothesis on GKE (without access to the master node) ?

Comment: Not directly, but if you give me bit of info about your cluster, I can take a look for you.

Comment: Have you had the time to look at this ? Now the routes aren't recreated but some containers get rescheduled twice in two days...

Comment: My instance group is now gke-rstck-dev-default-pool-98dd63bb-grp

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to look into this recently. We found a bug in 1.3 where some resources were recreated when one of the processes on the master restarted; it's possible that a similar bug exists in 1.2.4 for routes. At this point I'd suggest upgrading to 1.3.3 and see if you still see the routes occasionally being recreated.